# MySQL Drop Table Inside Trgigger

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, phpmyadmin, drop-table

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_alis AFTER INSERT ON alis_acik_emirler
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

    DROP TABLE alis2;

    CREATE TABLE alis2 (
        emirID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        userID int,
        fiyat int,
        adet int,
        doldurulan_adet int,
        kalan_adet int,
        market_tipi int,
        PRIMARY KEY(emirID)
    );

END;
```

> ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''DROP TABLE alis2'' at line 6

I can't drop table inside trigger. How can I do it?

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS alis2;
```

I tried this but it doesn't work.

Comment: How can you drop a table in a trigger?  That is not the question.  *Why* would you want to do such a thing?  I cannot readily think of a scenario where it would make sense.

Comment: Very Very bad design... If you use the multi insert `INSERT ... VALUES(1),(1),(1)`  the  `FOR EACH ROW` within the trigger will cause the trigger code to be executed three times meaning the table wil be dropped three times and created three times..

Answer (score 0):

I cannot figure out a good reason why you would want to drop a table in a trigger.  But you are dropping and recreating the table.  Perhaps you just want to truncate the table/remove all the rows:

```
delete a from alis2 a;
```

This will remove all the rows in the table.

Comment: Thaks for answer. I tried it but it gives an error.  
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' ' at line 6

How can I fix it?

Comment: `TRUNCATE TABLE` causes an [implicit commit](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/implicit-commit.html), so that's out, too.  OP is trying to do something that fundamentally does not belong in a trigger.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot . . . Do you think `delete from alis2` would work -- if that is what the OP intends?

Comment: Yes, that should be fine, if that's what's really needed.